# How can i limit rows to just 1 entry per day?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to limit my results to one row per day, that is the newest one for every day when i do:

`SELECT * FROM reports WHERE item = :item_id ORDER BY date DESC`

Only 1 record per day, the records selected for each day needs to be the latest one at that day as well.

I really have no idea what i should try. Search results gave me no directions.
I am looking for a complete solution.
Here is example data from my table, in JSON, selected for just a single item:

```
[{
        "id": "62",
        "user": "7",
        "item": "19333",
        "instant_buy": "798000",
        "instant_sell": "675000",
        "upvotes": "0",
        "downvotes": "0",
        "created": "2017-06-18 14:01:32"
    },
    {
        "id": "61",
        "user": "7",
        "item": "19333",
        "instant_buy": "899999",
        "instant_sell": "735647",
        "upvotes": "0",
        "downvotes": "0",
        "created": "2017-06-18 11:48:25"
    },
    {
        "id": "55",
        "user": "4",
        "item": "19333",
        "instant_buy": "1387166",
        "instant_sell": "1050000",
        "upvotes": "0",
        "downvotes": "0",
        "created": "2017-06-17 12:11:30"
    },
    {
        "id": "38",
        "user": "4",
        "item": "19333",
        "instant_buy": "1850000",
        "instant_sell": "900000",
        "upvotes": "0",
        "downvotes": "0",
        "created": "2017-06-16 15:48:02"
    },
    {
        "id": "36",
        "user": "1",
        "item": "19333",
        "instant_buy": "1529350",
        "instant_sell": "900000",
        "upvotes": "1",
        "downvotes": "0",
        "created": "2017-06-16 14:26:41"
    }]
```

Comment: By using the LIMIT clause http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

Comment: @jaypandya it seems you didn't see my example nor understand my question, i need One row per Day, there exist multiple days and multiple records Per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coud use a join with the user and max(created) grouped by user and date()

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM reports r
  INNER JOIN ( 
    select user, max(created) max_created
    from reports 
    group by user, date(created)
  )  t on t.user = r.user and t.max_created = r_created
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` on `date` column. Something similar to

```
SELECT * FROM reports 
WHERE item = :item_id 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d-%Y') 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like that:

```
select reports.* 
from reports inner join 
  (select distinct date(Date), (select ID from reports 
      where date(Date) = date(r1.Date) and item = :item_id
      order by Date desc 
      limit 1) ID 
    from Reports r1 where item = :item_id) s1 
 on reports.id = s1.id
```

depending if you want the first or the last entry of the date you should change the ordering the s1 subquery